# Generic 'member function' wrapper for other member function(s)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I have an interface where I *have to* pass on member function pointer which are static cast'ed to a base pointer and behind our backs stored as a void pointer and invocation type ([mfc](/questions/tagged/mfc) [message tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc?view=vs-2019)).

I have created a wrapper that does some exception handling (very simpel try/catch to catch std::runtime_error) since this is tedious and error prone to maintain in every single user callback.

So far, the following wrapper is actually working out fairly well (*The idea is to grab the member function pointer directly as a value template parameter* - in essence giving a member function wrapper for each and every callback function.):

```
class MyClass : public CWnd/*example*/{
public:
      template<void (MyClass::*f)(CCmdUI*)>
      void Dispatch(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) {
        try {
          (this->*f)(pCmdUI);
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
          //handle error
        }
      }
};
```

But in order to avoid having an explicit overload for each type of call - would it be possible to parametize the argument list ?

Illustration (*note this doesn't work*):

```
      template<void (MyClass::*f)(Args...)>
      void Dispatch(Args... args) {
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], you are much more likely to get a response if people can paste your code into a compiler and fiddle with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using C++17, you can use `auto` on template parameters:

```cpp
template<auto f, typename... Args>
      void Dispatch(Args... args) {
      //...
```

And invoke them normally by passing a pointer to member function as template argument #1. [Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/jPsWFt).

If you need to check whether `f` is a pointer to member function of that class, you can use some `static_assert` statements before invoking `(this->*f)(args...)`.

And a small thing: if you're using rvalue semantics, it's also a good idea to receive `Args&&`and use `std::forward`.

Comment: Using `Args&&... args` seems to *not* work with overload resolution, but `Args... args` does